# Building a python animal guessing game

Tags: python

I'm in a basic programming class and we have to make an animal guessing game. The basic idea is to create a dictionary of animals and attributes, and have the user guess the attribute and output yes or no and if they guess the animal's name print you win or try again. I'm stuck on getting the code to work correctly when the user input's an animal's name or attribute and print the correct response. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import random
animal = {'lion': ['mane', 'teeth', 'pride', 'Africa', 'predator'],
'tiger': ['stripes', 'fur', 'endangered', 'cat', 'claws'],
'bear': ['hibernates', 'North America', 'Brown', 'Fur', 'Strong'],
'owl': ['hoot', 'nocturnal', 'flies', 'big eyes', 'eats mice'],
'frog': ['pond', 'green', 'tongue', 'amphibian', 'eats flies'],
'toucan': ['rainbow', 'long beak', 'South America', 'tropical', 'wings'],
'monkey': ['eats bananas', 'trees', 'tail', 'swing', 'primate'],
'shark': ['ocean', 'dangeous', 'cartilege', 'sharp teeth', 'fins'],
'zebra': ['stripes', 'black and white', 'africa', 'safari', 'hoofs'],
'wolverine': ['vicious', 'skunk bear', 'brown', 'small', 'fast']}

randomanimal = random.choice(dict(enumerate(animal)))
key = random.choice(animal.keys())
values = random.choice(animal.values())
print ("Let's play a game!")
print ("Guess the animal I'm thinking of.")
guess = raw_input('What animal am I thinking of?')
if guess == "value":
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
if guess == "key":
    print("You Win!")
else:
    print("Try Again.")
```

Comment: `if guess == "value"` looks for a exact string `value`

Answer (score 1):

`animal.keys()` give you a list of all the keys in your dictionary. using `random.choice` on that will give you a random `animal(key)`. Next you want the `values` of THAT animal. So I use the`.get` on the randomly chosen animal

Do you display the `attributes` to the user? and based on that he makes a guess? If yes then this will work.

```
import random

animal = {'lion': ['mane', 'teeth', 'pride', 'Africa', 'predator'],
'tiger': ['stripes', 'fur', 'endangered', 'cat', 'claws'],
'bear': ['hibernates', 'North America', 'Brown', 'Fur', 'Strong'],
'owl': ['hoot', 'nocturnal', 'flies', 'big eyes', 'eats mice'],
'frog': ['pond', 'green', 'tongue', 'amphibian', 'eats flies'],
'toucan': ['rainbow', 'long beak', 'South America', 'tropical', 'wings'],
'monkey': ['eats bananas', 'trees', 'tail', 'swing', 'primate'],
'shark': ['ocean', 'dangeous', 'cartilege', 'sharp teeth', 'fins'],
'zebra': ['stripes', 'black and white', 'africa', 'safari', 'hoofs'],
'wolverine': ['vicious', 'skunk bear', 'brown', 'small', 'fast']}

randomanimal = random.choice(animal.keys())

values = animal.get(randomanimal)
print ("Let's play a game!")
print ("Guess the animal I'm thinking of.")

while True:
    guess = raw_input('What animal am I thinking of?')
    if guess == randomanimal:
        print "Correct guess. The animal i though of is %s" %randomanimal
        break
    else:
        print "nope"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is code you are looking for. Tested this out. Working Perfectly (Y). Try this out.

```
import random
animal = {'lion': ['mane', 'teeth', 'pride', 'Africa', 'predator'],
'tiger': ['stripes', 'fur', 'endangered', 'cat', 'claws'],
'bear': ['hibernates', 'North America', 'Brown', 'Fur', 'Strong'],
'owl': ['hoot', 'nocturnal', 'flies', 'big eyes', 'eats mice'],
'frog': ['pond', 'green', 'tongue', 'amphibian', 'eats flies'],
'toucan': ['rainbow', 'long beak', 'South America', 'tropical', 'wings'],
'monkey': ['eats bananas', 'trees', 'tail', 'swing', 'primate'],
'shark': ['ocean', 'dangeous', 'cartilege', 'sharp teeth', 'fins'],
'zebra': ['stripes', 'black and white', 'africa', 'safari', 'hoofs'],
'wolverine': ['vicious', 'skunk bear', 'brown', 'small', 'fast']}

randomanimal = random.choice(dict(enumerate(animal)))
guess = ""
attributes = animal[randomanimal]
print ("Let's play a game!")
print ("Guess the animal I'm thinking of.")

while guess != randomanimal:
    if guess in attributes:
        print ("yes")
    elif guess in animal.keys():
        print ("Try Again")
    elif guess != "":
        print ("no")

    guess = raw_input('What animal am I thinking of?')

print ("You Win")
```

Hope this helps.